# In unity, set transform.forward cause transform.position change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I set transform.forward perfect in horizontal move, but when i use it in vertical move, see my gif, `transform.forward = newForward` will cause transform.position change, **how to make character forward but don't change transform.position**

[image]

here is my full script:

```
public class TestVerticalMoveForward : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject from;

    private GameObject to;
    private GameObject target;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        from = GameObject.Find("From");
        to = GameObject.Find("To");
        target = from;
    }

    private float speed = 10;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var offset = target.transform.position - transform.position;
        var forward = offset.normalized;
        var offset2 = speed * Time.deltaTime * forward;
        if (offset.magnitude <= offset2.magnitude)
        {
            transform.position = target.transform.position;
            if (target == to)
            {
                target = from;
            }
            else
            {
                target = to;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += offset2;
        }

        if (offset != Vector3.zero)
        {
            transform.forward = offset;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you only want to rotate the object without moving it then don't change the position like: `transform.position += offset2;`

Comment: Yes, I know this way, but in most case, I should make character face target, I guess I can manually rotate character to instead of transform.forward, but I think it's a little difficult

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution and reason,

## solution:

here is fixed result

[image]

I use `Quaternion.LookRotation` instead of `transform.forward=`

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Script.Ro.Ext;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestVerticalMoveForward : MonoBehaviourExt
{
    private GameObject from;

    private GameObject to;

    private GameObject target;
//    private GameObject center;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        from = GameObject.Find("From");
        to = GameObject.Find("To");
//        center = GameObject.Find("Character/Center");
        target = from;
    }

    private float speed = 10;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Watch("center.transform.position", transform.position);
        var offset = target.transform.position - transform.position;

        var forward = offset.normalized;
        var offset2 = speed * Time.deltaTime * forward;
        if (offset.magnitude <= offset2.magnitude)
        {
            transform.position += offset;
            if (target == to)
            {
                target = from;
            }
            else
            {
                target = to;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += offset2;
        }

        if (offset != Vector3.zero)
        {
           var upAxis =  transform.rotation * Vector3.up;
            transform.rotation =
                Quaternion.LookRotation(target.transform.position - transform.position, upAxis);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

## reason

unity has

```
Quaternion LookRotation(Vector3 forward, Vector3 upwards = Vector3.up);
```

I guess `transform.forward =` invoke internal LookRotation code and always set `upwards = Vector3.up`(y axis), in horizontal move, it work perfect, but in vertical move, it perform unexpectly

so imagine object has center-up-axis, for ex, to humanoid object,  the up axis, is body center to head center axis, to make sure vertical move perform like horizontal move, LookRotation's upwards should always be center-up-axis, see my above code, this center-up-axis should be:

```
       var upAxis =  transform.rotation * Vector3.up ;
```